# Return to source queue does not work

Tags: nservicebus

I have some messages that wound up in the error queue for some reason. I'm trying to use the ReturnToSourceQueue.exe utility but it fails. Here's what happens:

```
PS C:\tools\NServicebus> .\ReturnToSourceQueue.exe
Please enter the error queue you would like to use:
nservicebus_errors
Please enter the id of the message you'd like to return to its source queue, or 'all' to do so for all messages in the q
ueue.
all
Attempting to return message to source queue. Please stand by.
Returning message with id 60dda2a3-e60f-4eaf-a40b-3a081cde0258\4114510 to queue
Could not return message to source queue.
Reason: Format name is invalid.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, ITransaction transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTr
ansactionType transactionType)
   at NServiceBus.Tools.Management.Errors.ReturnToSourceQueue.Class1.ReturnMessage(String messageId)
   at NServiceBus.Tools.Management.Errors.ReturnToSourceQueue.Class1.ReturnMessageToSourceQueue(String messageId)
Message ID not found in time. Going to look in message labels for original ID.
Returning message with id 60dda2a3-e60f-4eaf-a40b-3a081cde0258\4114510 to queue
Could not return message to source queue.
Reason: Format name is invalid.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, ITransaction transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTr
ansactionType transactionType)
   at NServiceBus.Tools.Management.Errors.ReturnToSourceQueue.Class1.ReturnMessage(String messageId)
   at NServiceBus.Tools.Management.Errors.ReturnToSourceQueue.Class1.ReturnMessageToSourceQueue(String messageId)
Returning message with id 60dda2a3-e60f-4eaf-a40b-3a081cde0258\4192925 to queue
```

Any idea what's going on here? What does "Format name is invalid" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The tool pulls the name of the queue out of the message headers which are stored in the Extension property of the message(assuming MSMQ here).  This means that the name that is being derived from the tool is invalid.  I would take a look at the message headers and see what it has for the source queue.  This is set by NSB internally so I'm guessing it is something environmental(clustered or remote queues maybe)?